# What is the relationship between HTML and data analysis?

Tags: html, data-science, data-analysis

In reference to this [infographic](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/data-science-industry-infographic) about the data science industry.

I have a question about the relationship between HTML and data analysis!

Is there really a relationship between them?

If so, what is this relationship?

How can we use HTML in data analysis?

Comment: HTML is often the presentation layer for infographics and other analysis.

Comment: Thank you! but can you provide some details about this? @Mark_M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML is not a programming language. It is a document markup language. It really can't do much on its own. It can present results but offers limited interactivity. I think when people say HTML they really mean the combination of HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

With JavaScript added, you could technically code anything, though, in practical terms, it's only going to be suited for so many things due to performance concerns and the like.

As Mark_M said, it's mostly used for the presentation layer. This is especially important in the context of business. Let's go through an example. Say you build a model that predicts which of your companies product an individual customer or prospective customer would be most likely to purchase. What are you, as the analyst, going to do with that information? Do you care personally that Sally M wants to buy widget A and Frank R wants to buy widget B? Sure your company cares. Sure your pay is loosely based on the performance of the company. But you have plenty of other things to analyze. So now what?

Do you know who really cares about that information? The Sales Team. That's their whole job. Their pay is based on commission. They know how to act on that information. You let the sales team know this, they do their thing, you get your own performance pay, the company does well, everyone wins.

Now, how do you tell the Sales team this information? Do you let them call you every time they need a lead? Do you give them some sloppily written code in MATLAB or a command line Python client? Do you give them the math equations and tell to figure it out?

Now, remember, a lot of the sales team are not very technically savvy. Even if they sell technology, they barely know enough about it to sell it. The Sales team doesn't know what a -345 error code means. They interface with the customer and ask a member of the support or engineering team for help as needed. The sales team can barely handle the basics of Excel. I would bet you that 90% of the sales team doesn't even know what a "for loop", but that's ok, you don't know how to get that guy on the fence to hand over his signature. People have different strengths.

So what now? You need Bob the salesman to have all the information he needs without bothering you while you code up the next analysis. If you make it too hard, they won't use it. That's just the way life works.

Do you know what's really easy to use? Web applications. Bob the salesman can figure out any web application, especially if it's well designed. So you code up your analysis in the form of a web application. Maybe you have a web design team at your company to redesign your web application, to make it more user-friendly, but they don't know the details of your model. You must code up a prototype web application to allow other people to run and use your model.

Data analysts and data scientist (some at least) are expected to write prototype web applications. You might hear these things called "dashboards." It isn't very hard actually. There are technologies such as R Shiny and Bokeh to make it easy peasy, at least compared to the harder parts of your job.

The application, of course, might not make it out to the general internet, or it might. But it could very well at least make it onto your company intranet. The old way of doing things is companies keeping all their analysis in Excel files and passing those around. The new way is web applications on the intranet.

Your models are totally useless if no one turns them into actionable information and then actually acts on them. The company isn't paying you to build models. They are paying you to tell them what they should do to make more money. You must make it easy enough for them to achieve that.

That's the relationship. In short, it's the presentation layer, ha.